# Time sensitive handshaking between PLC and motor controller

Tags: vb.net, handshake, plc

I'm trying to setup handshaking between my PLC (using ladder-logic) and a motor controller (using VB). I am using implicit communication meaning the PLC has some Output registers it can write to that the motor controller see's as input registers. And likewise the controller has some output registers that it can use to write back and the PLC will see these as inputs. It's important to note that neither device can change the registers that it sees as inputs.

That fact is important because normally I would have the PLC send a command by setting a register equal to 1, then once the motor controller has completed that command it would set that same register back to zero and the process could repeat. But since the motor controller cannot set the same register back to zero it instead has to signal the PLC with a different register. In my PLC code I have the "command" register revert to zero when the "acknowledge" register is turned on, but depending on where the PLC code is at the time it may just issue the command again before it checks the "acknowledge" register. Currently when I issue a command to move the motor, it will move 3 or 6 times.

Is there a way that common way to handshake when two separate registers are being used?

Comment: Your PLC should only issue a command to the control when the interop signal transitions from 0 to 1.  Simply detected by keeping a copy of the signal.  Your VB code needs to only issue a command when it knows that the controller is idle.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of event-driven versus cyclic. If this is a truly time-critical task then the last thing you should be using is VB. Why can't you communicate directly between the PLC and the MC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't send commands as on/off but as a unique, increasing version number. The receiver acts upon each new number only once. Reset to zero after e.g. a day. I've used this "protocol" over and over again in container crane controls. If the receiver has seen a certain version, it reflects the number back to acknowledge. Since the whole thing reflects the course of affairs tearing a slip of an entrance ticket and giving the (numbered) ticket back, I've called it "Ticked and Slip protocol". It's working flawlessly on several cranes for 15 years now (and for many other communications between unsynced devices).